# Android - Casting model that is not in the Adapter

Tags: android, json

I have a ListView that is using a custom adapter to populate its rows.

I want to get two String values from the adapter that I have clicked, so I used getItem method:

```
@Override
public UserItemsModel getItem(int i) {
    return arrUserItems.get(i);
}
```

As you can see above, I'm suing `UserItemsModel` as a reference to get the item id.

So, in the list fragment, I retrieve the values I desired by using onListItemClicked method:

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


        UserItemsModel userItemsModel = (UserItemsModel) l.getAdapter().getItem(position);
        String item_id = userItemsModel.getItem_id();
        //String user_id = userItemsModel.getUser_id(); This is not in the UserItemsModel
        mListener.onUserItemSelected(user_id, item_id);
    }
```

However, the `user_id` is not in the UserItemsModel (as I have modeled from a Json format), instead `user_id` is in the other model that the adapter doesn't use.

UserItemsModel look like this:

```
public class UserItemsModel {
    private String item_id; // i can get this
    private String item_name;
```

No user_id that I wanted. But, it is in `UserShopModel` which is a parent of `UserItemsModel`

```
public class UserShopModel {

    private String user_id; // i can't get this
    private String username;
    private String name;
```

When I run the app, it throws an error that says something like `Cannot Cast UserShopModel into UserItemsModel`

Anyone know how to get around this? If anything unclear please let me know.

**UDPATE:**

Here is how the JSON look like:

```
{
  "results": {
    "user_id": "2947",
    "username": "100001235797881",
    "name": "Fast Reload",
    "email": "atiqahfatin76@yahoo.com",
    "phone": "6Lparw1NrMmpu7gd2U18mg==",
    "avatar": "http:\/\/ked.ai\/uploads\/avatar\/2947_avatar.png",
    "shop_name": "FastReload",
    "shop_desc": "our vision is to provide Fast And Easy reload service in malaysia. After One time registeration You can top up anytime anywhere at any number with lower price using sms system.24\/7, no internet connection required. Click here http:\/\/www.fastreload.tk\/ For more info and registeration .Thank You =)",
    "shop_namespace": "FastReload",
    "shop_canvas": "http:\/\/ked.ai\/uploads\/canvas\/2947_canvas.png",
    "profile": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Shop Name",
        "content": "FastReload"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Shop Namespace",
        "content": "FastReload"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Shop Description",
        "content": "our vision is to provide Fast And Easy reload service in malaysia. After One time registeration You can top up anytime anywhere at any number with lower price using sms system.24\/7, no internet connection required. Click here http:\/\/www.fastreload.tk\/ For more info and registeration .Thank You =)"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Customer Service",
        "content": "operation hours 9 am to 9 pm"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Trust Level",
        "content": "0%"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Bank Details",
        "content": null
      }
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "item_id": "20321",
        "name": "Fast And Easy Reload Service",
        "price": "20",
        "description": "  our vision is to provide Fast And Easy reload service in malaysia. After One time registeration You can top up anytime anywhere at any number with lower price using sms system.24\/7, no internet connection required.Click here http:\/\/www.fastreload.tk\/ For more info and registeration .Thank You =)",
        "category_id": "127",
        "category": "Services",
        "vanity": [

        ],
        "thumbnail": {
          "image50": "http:\/\/ked.ai\/uploads\/item\/100001235797881\/2947_1391259043.71a8deec82a92fc51acfa63c7a87c263_50.jpg",
          "image100": "http:\/\/ked.ai\/uploads\/item\/100001235797881\/2947_1391259043.71a8deec82a92fc51acfa63c7a87c263_100.jpg"
        }
      }
    ],
    "vanities": [

    ],
    "categories": [
      {
        "category_id": "127",
        "category_name": "Services",
        "category_url": "http:\/\/ked.ai\/FastReload\/category\/services",
        "count": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": ""
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is the type of the arrUserItems?

Comment: Buddy, your information is unclear. Can you please post your JSON response sample. Because, I think you might have done wrong data modelling. I want to know how UserItemsModel & UserShopModel are related.

Comment: I've updated the question. Added JSON structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to obtain the user id from the ShopModel, then the only way you might want to do this, is:

```
1. Either pass the userShopModel as an argument to the constructor of the adapter. 
The assumption you might want to make is, UserShopModel and UserItemModel 
have the same number of items(that is the size is the same)

2. The other thing you could do is, inside every userItemModel create a property 
of the type UserShopModel such that for every item that you click, 
you not only get the item_id but also the user_id
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I used option no 2 and now it works. Thank you. But, what is wrong here? Is it because of the JSON structure isn't properly managed or I've modeled it wrongly? Thanks again for your thoughts.

Comment: The json format is correct probably the way you have modeled it is not the perfect way . You could have had a usershop model as the main class with the shop name n all as the attributes. And the list of items as an attribute too. And when filling in the lst you could have passed the list of items only. Because, practically, its a shop that has items.